# Regular expression for email that allows leading/trailing spaces but no other invalid email characters

Tags: regex, email

I have a regular expression to validate an email address. It supports trailing and leading spaces, since I want to allow users to make that mistake, I'll just trim the email value on the backend. This logic is exactly what I want.

This is the regular expression I have right now: `\s*[-+.'\w]+@[-.\w]+\.[-.\w]+\s*`

However, my current expression also allows ``` and `,` characters in the email address. How can I make sure that only characters valid for an email address are supported, but also allow trailing or leading spaces?

So these addresses are currently allowed, which I don't want:

```
dfdfd@bcvb.com,
dfdfd@bcvb.com`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try out the regex

```
^(?!['`])\s*[-+.'\w]+@[-.\w]+\.[-.\w]+\s*$
```

see the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/fwcMA2/2) or use the regex

```
^(?=[\w\s-+.])\s*[-+.'\w]+@[-.\w]+\.[-.\w]+\s*$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/fwcMA2/3)

Comment: Thank you! It however also accepts this email address as valid: `'d@dfgdfg.com`, I can remove `'` from the regex (I know it was in my original one too), but email address never have that character right?

Comment: please check out the updated demo and regex

Comment: add all invalid characters in the square brackets in (?!['`])

Comment: Thanks. But is there no way to do it the other way around? Instead of having to define all non-allowed chars, define the chars that ARE allowed? I mean: `[a-zA-Z0-9._-+]` (anything else?)...isn't that a shorter way to do it?

Comment: yes try ^(?=[\w\s])\s*[-+.'\w]+@[-.\w]+\.[-.\w]+\s*$

Comment: add everything allowed in the square bracket in (?=[\w\s])

Comment: One last thing: a lot of users enter the wrong TLD: ".con" instead of ".com". How would I specifically disallow ".con" as the TLD?